# Scaffolding for bootstrap grid with PHP loop & mysqli

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

thanks for taking a look at my question.

I'm trying to get PHP to output bootstrap rows that only contain 2 col-md-6 columns, instead of outputting 1 row with 1 col for each iteration.

Searching here on Stackoverflow I found a solution that makes sense but when I implement it, the HTML that I get makes no sense!

**I should be getting this:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

**...But I'm getting this:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CODE:**

```
<?php
require_once('somedb.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notyourbusiness");
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    $i = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';

    if($rowCount > 0){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    ?>

       <?php echo '<div class="col-md-6">'; ?>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/project/<?php echo $row['thumb'] ?>" class="work-thumbnail" width="100"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><h2><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h2></a>
       <?php echo '</div>'; ?>

    <?php
     $i++;
     if ($i%2 == 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';

     } ?>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us more information? It seems that the first  is comming from outside of this php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notyourbusiness");
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$i = 0;

if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $row_draw = ($i % 2 == 0) ? true : false;

        # Start row div
        if ($row_draw)
        {
            print "<div class='row'>";
        }

        # Print Column
        print "<div class='col-md-6'>";
        ?>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/project/<?php echo $row['thumb'] ?>" class="work-thumbnail" width="100"></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <h2><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h2>
            </a>
        <?php
        print "</div>";

        # End row div
        if ($row_draw)
        {
            print "</div>";
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```